# VBA: How to trigger event when selected value in combobox changes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, onchange

I am new to VBA and would like to trigger a simple change event when the selection in a combobox (within a UserForm) changes.

I tried both `Private Sub myCombo_AfterUpdate()` and `Private Sub myCombo_Change()` but in both cases nothing happens when I select a different value in the combobox.

Is this the wrong approach for comboboxes ?

**My Sub starts as follows as I want to compare the currently selected item in the dropdown with the value in a table:**

```
Private Sub myCombo_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.myCombo.Value = Worksheets(8).Range("A4") Then
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: The correct one to use is "_Change". Please confirm your combobox name matches the subroutine. I would go to the code window, hit the dropdown, select the combobox "myCombo".

Comment: Thanks. I checked that, it's correct. It seems the issue is with the cell reference.

Comment: It seems to be the worksheet number. When I replace this with the name of the actual sheet then it works fine. The sheet is Sheet8 - do I have to address this different when using the sheet number ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use sheet name... You don't have any hidden sheets do you? Using the sheet# would apply to the nth physical sheet - including hidden.

Comment: No, no hidden sheets.

Comment: Be aware, that the _Change - event is also triggered, when data source of a combobox (ie. the list) changes. I prefer using _Click (wich is also triggered if the contents changes) or best _DropButtonClick (wich is only triggered, if the user klicks on the dropButton).

Comment: @DrMarbuse , can I use _Click when I have a Combobox in a cell ? And after selecting one item in the combox I show a messagebox.? Or shall I use _Change both does not work really

Comment: sheet8 is not equal to sheets(8). the first depends on creation time/index, and the second depends on the order you arranged it in your workbook tabs.
To avoid unnecessary confusion, use name of sheet.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when new sheets are created, namings are represented like this: `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, etc. They are numbered in the creation order.

The 'functions' `Worksheets(1)`, `Worksheets(2)` can be used to [get sheet by index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets). This index can be either number of sheet name:

> Use Worksheets (index), where index is the worksheet index number or name, to return a single Worksheet object.

It basically means that `Worksheets(i)` returns the current `i`-th sheet of your workbook (if `i` is an integer).

The problem is that the sheet numbers (e.g. '1' in `Sheet1` and `Worksheets(1)`) *are not necessarily the same*. They are the same by default if sheets are created one by one and the order is unchanged. However, there may be multiple cases when the numbers do not match.

Therefore it is **strongly recommended to get worksheets by name** and not by number, i.e.:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

and not

```
Worksheets(1)
```

Also, there is still an option to refer to the sheet as the object (`Sheet1`).

##### P.S. An example how to reproduce the worksheet index mismatch

1. Create at least 2 sheets in MS Excel with default names. In our example. `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are created.
2. Add a `Button` object on a `Sheet1`.
3. Transfer `Sheet2` to the left to make it the leftmost page (as it showed on the screenshot).
4. Add a macros to the `Button` object on `Sheet1` and add a breakpoint to the macros. Also, using `Add Watch...` command add variables to the debugging section

   - `Worksheets(1).CodeName`
   - `Worksheets(2).CodeName`
5. If you click on the `Button` object and go to the VB code window, in the `Watches` window you'll see that

- `Worksheets(1).CodeName = "Sheet2"` (the leftmost Sheet)
- `Worksheets(2).CodeName = "Sheet1"` (the second Sheet)

**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSK7X.png)**